# JavaScript replace array value and shift increment number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array which values are like this :

**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9** (based on row of the table)

In my case if i select as "**istirahat**" at 2nd row, I want the column called **jam ke** become like this :

```
1
-
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

[image]

My idea is I collect them to array : 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
if i selected index 1, then i'll replace 2 to "" so the values become :

[1,"",2,3,4,5,6,7,8] but I confused to replace and make it to sequence after "" << empty string

```
$(document).on('change','.jenis_mapel', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */
            var index = $(this).data('jam');//value of index row
            var expect = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if (arr[i] == index) 
                {
                    expect = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    var curr = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = expect;
                }
            }

            console.log(arr);
        });
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could splice the array ([`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) and insert a value at a certain position.

This mutates the original array.

```js
function add(array, index, value) {
    array.splice(index, 0, value);
}

function remove(array, index) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}



var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

add(array, 1, '-');
console.log(...array);

remove(array, 1);

console.log(...array);
```

Comment: I just found the bug , when i select an option the number should back again any idea to do it ?

Comment: you could delete with `splice`, too. please have a look to the description (link above). then take `array.splice(index, 1)` for deleting an item at the index.

Comment: yeah the number that replaced by empty string is back (number 2 ) but the next numbers are wrong and not sequence again (after 2 the output is 4,5 etc), plz look my screenshot here : https://i.postimg.cc/7Y8crTVY/image.png

Comment: it should work. maybe you have taken the wrong index.

Comment: it's not working when the empty string greather than 1 ... [1,"",2,"",4,5,6,7,8,9] <<< it's won't work ...

Comment: please see in the snippets, you can remove one or more items from the array.

Comment: oooh i see the exact bug is ... if the array values are : [1, "", "", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] when i remove index 2 , the index 2 still be empty string ... cuz shift to left